# Adjacency Matrix Setting Links Incorrectly

Tags: c++, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to implement an adjacency matrix for a text based "3-D maze" (implemented as a 7x7 matrix). For some reason my current code is making it so that the player always has the option to travel in the downward direction, which shouldn't be happening. My test lines indicate that the file input is correct, and that the pIdx, idx, and dCode parameters are making it to the second function with the correct values.

Is the problem just in the very last line of the second function?

```
    {    

   //This function reads in the directions from a file. If it reads in -1, there should not be a
    //link to that direction.

    // Read North 
    getNextLine(line, 128);
    link = atoi(line); 
    setLink(i, link, 'N');

    // Read South 
    getNextLine(line, 128);
    link = atoi(line);   
    setLink(i, link, 'S');

    // Read East
    getNextLine(line, 128);
    link = atoi(line);    
    setLink(i, link, 'E');

    // Read West
    getNextLine(line, 128);
    link = atoi(line);    
    setLink(i, link, 'W');

    // Read Up
    getNextLine(line, 128);
    link = atoi(line);    
    setLink(i, link, 'U');

    // Read Down
    getNextLine(line, 128);
    link = atoi(line);    
    setLink(i, link, 'D');
}
```

This function is where the problem is:

```
 void Map::setLink(int pIdx, int linkIdx, char dCode)
{
  if ((pIdx<0)||(pIdx>6))
    {
        cout<<"pIdx invalid"<<endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
else if ((linkIdx<-1)||(linkIdx>6))
    {
        cout<<"LinkIdx invalid"<<endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
else if ((dCode!='N')&& (dCode!='S')&& (dCode!='E')&& (dCode!='W')&&(dCode!='U')&&(dCode!='D'))
    {
        cout<<"dCode must equal 'N', 'S','E', 'W', 'U', or 'D'."<<endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

m_cAdjMatrix[pIdx][linkIdx]=dCode;
}
```

File Input:
-1
3
1
-1
-1
-1
-1
4
2
0
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
1
14
-1
0
6
-1
-1
-1
-1
1
-1
5
-1
16
-1
-1
8
3
-1
-1
-1
3
9
7
-1
-1
-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `linkIdx` is -1, the assignment at the end of `setLink` will access outside the bounds of the array (`m_cAdjMatrix[pIdx][-1]`) resulting in Undefined Behavior.

You don't want to do that assignment if `linkIdx` is -1.